# java virtual machine is required to use portal message

Tags: java

I am running into a bit issue here where the platform/website I am trying to access only works properly with an old version of java, but with the older java it pops up a message "the java virtual machine is required to use the portal, you will be prompted to download the latest version", and it won't let me click on the message at the bottom which to run the old java at this time and switch to update site.

Any ideas I could get the message off so I am able to run older version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No specific idea besides: make sure you get rid of that requirement as soon as you can. Outdated software is always always always a security risk.

Comment: Contact the website owner to tell them they are using outdated technology.